# Irkutsk to Ulaanbaatar by train or bus?

Tags: transportation, russia, mongolia, ulan-bator, irkutsk

I've tried using [tutu.ru](http://tutu.ru) for the trains, but it won't show me any train to [Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulan_Bator). Despite this I know there are daily trains.  What I don't know is what time they are, how long they take, and how much they cost?

In addition, there's talk of a bus from [Ulan Ude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulan-Ude) - although there may presumably be one from [Irkutsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irkutsk) too. Same questions - times, length of trip and cost, any help or websites with this on?

Final 'how to get somewhere' question on this trip, hopefully ;)

Comment: tutu.ru has information only for Russia and CIS trains, not international, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, given it'd worked in Kazakhstan I wondered if it was maybe where Russian trains went as well.  Ah well :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Information about Russian trains schedules can be found at the [official site of Russian Railways](http://eng.rzd.ru/isvp/public/rzdeng?STRUCTURE_ID=4137):

1. **Train #006Ь Moscow - Ulan-Bator** departure at 21:35 every Wednesday, Thursday, arrival at 06:30 every Monday, Tuesday. Stop in Irkutsk at 23:25 every Sunday, Monday respectively.
2. **Train Fares [#362 Irkutsk - Ulan-Bator](http://pass.rzd.ru/isvp/public/pass/express?schd_id=3&action=submit&layer_id=4925&train=362%D0%AB&STRUCTURE_ID=735&date=05.08&schd_ref_id=2&refererLayerId=4925)** departure at 17:15 every day, arrival at 06:10.

About buses from Ulan-Ude - there are some talks at local forums that buses are really go, every day, and during summer even more than one, but information is from 2009 year, and can't find any newer.
Buses (they said) departure at 10-00, and after 8-9 hours you are in Ulan-Bator, but can't find official link for it.

Comment: Haha, that's gold. I'll pass on Ulan Ude as running short on time - only 11 days of travel left. Train for me, that sounds perfect :)

Comment: Curses, what they don't mention is the international office closes earlier than the other ticket offices, so despite 20 spare seats, they can't sell me a ticket.  One more day in Irkutsk it is :)

Comment: @Mark Mayo even if you have a schedule of work time, there is no guarantee they will use it. :)

Comment: Nice. Was there first thing this morning and bought my ticket, so should be off tonight now :)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the bus from Ulan Ude to Ulaanbaatar is about 8 hours. For some reason, when you travel by train, the border controls alone take 9 hours. I never really quite figured out why it took so long and bus passengers don't seem to suffer this. So a train to Ulan Ude and the bus from there is a good option.

Another good reason to stop in Ulan Ude is that it means to get to travel past Lake Baikal by day - I can't recommend this enough, it was the highlight of our trip.

Comment: Thanks. Having now done this (it was August last year) I can confirm the border crossing takes all day.  You stop at the border and have 3-4 hours to just wander around, check out the market, get some food, and get back on for the security check. Then the train goes a little way down the track for the Mongolian check.  It all goes super-slow and takes forever, but if you accept it's happening, that's ok.  And yes, I did a couple of days on Olkhon island on Lake Baikal - it was magnificent :)

Comment: I have to say, 9 hours at the border wasn't my experience at all.  It took me little more than 2 hours last week.